# Google Cloud Speech response always empty error

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, google-cloud-speech

I am sending audio to GCS, via `"https://speech.googleapis.com/v1/speech:recognize?key=<my key>"`, the following way:

```
byte[] audioBytes = g_NPCAudioListener.GetAudioClipMonoData16(88200);

string jsonData = "{" +
      "\"config\": {" +
          "\"encoding\": \"LINEAR16\"," +
          "\"sampleRateHertz\": 48000," +
          "\"languageCode\": \"en-US\"" +
      "}," +
      "\"audio\": {" +
          "\"content\" : \"" + Convert.ToBase64String(audioBytes) + "\"" +
      "}" +
"}";

byte[] postData = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsonData);
g_NPCController.Debug("Sending to google: " + jsonData);
using (WWW req = new WWW(g_Google_Speech_URL, postData, g_JSONHeaders)) {
           yield return req;
           if (req.error == null) {
               g_NPCController.Debug(req.text.Replace("\n", "").Replace(" ", ""));
           } else {
               string msg = Convert.ToString(req.bytes);
               g_NPCController.Debug("Google Speech Error: " + req.error + "\n - error: " + req.text);
           }
 }
```

Everything is up to specification, however, I keep getting nothing but an error flag with an empty body.

While working on the main JSON impl, I was getting "Invalid parameter" and such... but now that I am streaming 88200 chunks of 16-bit uncompressed audio bytes, I keep getting an error with no text attached to it - not even a code. Did anyone come across a similar situation?

If relevant, the audio I get it from an AudioClip in Unity, then convert the 32-bit float[] to a byte[originalAudio.Length * sizeof(float)] and then to base64 as required.

Thanks.

Comment: Please add what you are doing. Speech to text or text to speech? Also, add your sending code. What you have you in your question is simply a variable and a value. You don't have the http request code which is important. Finally, post the error like it is.

Comment: The url is self explanatory if you are familiar with the api - this is not NLP. I added more context.

Comment: I was able to get a response by factoring the magnitude of the samples. So volume seems to be an issue with GCS.